# How to highlight features on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a map using D3 and am trying to add some dynamic highlighting to it. Ex., when you mouseover certain features, the border changes color/weight. I'm using the following code to try to accomplish this:

```
function setEnumerationUnits(manhattan, map, path, colorScale){

    //add Manhattan NTAs to map
    var manhattan = map.selectAll(".manhattan")
        .data(manhattan)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d){
            return "manhattan " + d.properties.ntacode;
        })
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("fill", function(d){
            return choropleth(d.properties, colorScale);
        })
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            highlight(d.properties);
        });

    //add style descriptor to each path
    var desc = manhattan.append("desc")
        .text('{"stroke": "#000", "stroke-width": "0.5px"}');
};
```

.
.
.

```
//function to highlight enumeration units and bars
function highlight(props){
    //change stroke
    var selected = d3.selectAll("." + props.ntaname)
        .style({
            "stroke": "blue",
            "stroke-width": "2"
        });
    setLabel(props);
};
```

I'm expecting to see features being outlined when I "brush" over them, but no luck. When I look at the console, I get type errors saying, "cannot read property 'style' of null" and "cannot read property 'html' of null". How can I change this so that the highlight shows up?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the whole datum to the `highlight` function, not only a single property.

So, instead of:

```
  .on("mouseover", function(d){
      highlight(d.properties);
  });
```

It should be:

```
  .on("mouseover", function(d){
      highlight(d);
  });
```

Or even shorter:

```
  .on("mouseover", highlight);
```

Finally, since you didn't share the `setLabel` function, I don't know if it requires a property or the whole datum. Therefore, you have to change that accordingly.

Comment: Oh, I see! I tried using the shortest version `.on("mouseover", highlight);` and that seems to have helped. However, I'm still seeing the "cannot read property 'style' of null" in reference to the highlight function. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Are you sure that you have any element with a class `props.ntaname`? Put this inside the highlight function and tell me the result: `console.log(d3.selectAll("." + props.ntaname).size())`. I suppose the result will be zero.

Comment: Update: I edited a couple of lines elsewhere in the code and now I'm getting no errors! But you're right, ` console.log(d3.selectAll("." + props.ntaname).size())` is returning an empty console. Then, when I mouse around the map, I'm getting user messages that say '0'.

Comment: Well, as I supposed, this is **another** issue: your selection is empty. I suggest that in this case you post another question, with all relevant details, regarding how to get the element you want. By the way, if you just want the path you're doing the mouseover, you can simply do `d3.select(this)`.