# Undefined properties in TopoJSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover

I'm working on a map where features will highlight as you mouse over them. I'm using the following code to do so, and it's displaying correctly. However, the interactivity isn't working. Nothing happens when I brush over features. I've added a console.log statement (props.ntaname) to find what can be going wrong, but this has added some more questions:

```
function setEnumerationUnits(manhattan, map, path, colorScale){

    //add Manhattan NTAs to map
    var manhattan = map.selectAll(".manhattan")
        .data(manhattan)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d){
            return "manhattan " + d.properties.ntacode;
        })
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("fill", function(d){
            return choropleth(d.properties, colorScale);
        })
        .on("mouseover", highlight);
    //add style descriptor to each path
    var desc = manhattan.append("desc")
        .text('{"stroke": "#000", "stroke-width": "0.5px"}');
};
```

.
.
.

```
//function to create coordinated bar chart
function setChart(csvData, colorScale){
    //create a second svg element to hold the bar chart
    var chart = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", chartWidth)
        .attr("height", chartHeight)
        .attr("class", "chart");

    //create a rectangle for chart background fill
    var chartBackground = chart.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "chartBackground")
        .attr("width", chartInnerWidth)
        .attr("height", chartInnerHeight)
        .attr("transform", translate);

    //set bars for each NTA
    var bars = chart.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(csvData)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .sort(function(a, b){
            return b[expressed]-a[expressed]
        })
        .attr("class", function(d){
            return "bar " + d.ntacode;
        })
        .attr("width", chartInnerWidth / csvData.length - 1)
        .on("mouseover", highlight);
/*      .on("mouseout", dehighlight)
        .on("mousemove", moveLabel) */;

    //add style descriptor to each rect
    var desc = bars.append("desc")
        .text('{"stroke": "none", "stroke-width": "0px"}');

    //create a text element for the chart title
    var chartTitle = chart.append("text")
        .attr("x", 55)
        .attr("y", 40)
        .attr("class", "chartTitle");

    //create vertical axis generator
    // var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    //  .scale(yScale)
    //  .orient("left");
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

    //place axis
    var axis = chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", translate)
        .call(yAxis);

    //create frame for chart border
    var chartFrame = chart.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "chartFrame")
        .attr("width", chartInnerWidth)
        .attr("height", chartInnerHeight)
        .attr("transform", translate);

    //set bar positions, heights, and colors
    updateChart(bars, csvData.length, colorScale);
};
```

.
.
.

```
//function to highlight enumeration units and bars
function highlight(props){
    //change stroke
    var selected = d3.selectAll(props.ntaname)
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .style("stroke-width", "2");
    //console.log(d3.selectAll("." + props.ntaname).size())
    console.log(props.ntaname)
    //setLabel(props);
};
```

In the console, when I mouse over features, the map (enumeration units function) returns 'undefined' statements, and the chart returns the proper neighborhood names. Still, the features don't change as I'm expecting them to visually. How can I edit this code to make this work?
[Data in CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXLOA.png)
[Data in TopoJSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXcrw.png)

Comment: Do you set a class using `ntaname` anywhere in the code? Also, would you mind deleting your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/55718530/5768908) since it seems to be useless?

Comment: It's never set as a class, but it is a common attribute between a csv file where I'm getting data and the TopoJSON that is displayed on the map. I'm console logging the TopoJSON and seeing attributes matched up correctly, but the 'ntacode' field is coming back "NaN". I'm thinking that's where the problem is. And sure thing

Comment: Well, if you never set the class, `selectAll` won't return anything. You have to explicitly set the class to the element.

Comment: I would like to help, but I can't recreate your issue. Can you provide links to your TopoJSON and TSV file and whatever is needed to recreate problem on my end? Also, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for sending that along. I'm fairly new to javascript and stackoverflow and it's taking a minute for me to figure out how to link to the files, but I will try to add them

Comment: When you class the features you use `d.properties.ntacode`, why are you using `props.ntacode` rather than `props.properties.ntacode` in the highlight function? Both props and d should be refering to the same thing: the datum. (You could have something elsewhere that makes this approach possible, but otherwise, that looks like a problem)